# Can't run bundle exec rake db:create in circleCI

Tags: postgresql, continuous-integration, circleci

I am trying to run `bundle exec rails yarn:instal` but it fails.

I am using image: postgres:latest and also have environment defined. I have installed postgres client too. My database.yml configuration is correct, as it was running fine on github actions, but i am getting following error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: The `development` database is not configured for the `development` environment.

  Available database configurations are:

  default
test
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb:177:in `resolve_symbol_connection'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb:127:in `resolve'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:353:in `resolve_config_for_connection'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:51:in `establish_connection'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:95:in `class_eval'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:95:in `block in execute_hook'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:85:in `with_execution_control'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:90:in `execute_hook'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `block in on_load'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:59:in `each'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:59:in `on_load'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:262:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
/home/circleci/project/config/environment.rb:7:in `<main>'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:348:in `require_environment!'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:511:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sentry-ruby-5.8.0/lib/sentry/rake.rb:24:in `execute'
/home/circleci/project/vendor/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:486:in `exec'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.22/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:120:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-2.3.22/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace
```

I've tried using different postgres images, but nothing seems to work. I checked if postgres server was running with psql command and it seems to be working too.

any solutions to this?